# How to implement onEndReached in horizontal list [react-native & reanimated 2]

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, react-native-reanimated-v2

I need to create an horizontal FlatList, maybe like instagram stories, and trigger the onEndReached function at some time to know when download more items from backend.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I've tried to solve, maybe will be useful for someone, write me if you think there's error of maybe you have a better solution:

where:

`maxBeforeTrigger:` the number of list's cells to scroll every time before triggering onEndReached. (similar to onEndThreshold for vertical flatlists).

`stepWidth:` cell dimension.

```
const AnimatedFlatList = Animated.createAnimatedComponent(FlatList);

var stepIndicies = [];

const AnimatedHFlatList = forwardRef(
  (
    {
      onScroll,
      onEndReached,
      maxBeforeTrigger = 2,
      stepWidth = width,
      ...props
    },
    ref
  ) => {
    const scrollX = useSharedValue(0);

    const [endIndex, setEndIndex] = useState(1);

    const _onScroll = useAnimatedScrollHandler(
      ({ contentOffset: { x } }) => {
        scrollX.value = x;

        onScroll && runOnJS(onScroll)(x);

        const currentStepIndex = Math.max(
          0,
          Math.round(x / (maxBeforeTrigger * stepWidth))
        );

        if (
          x <= stepWidth * maxBeforeTrigger * endIndex &&
          endIndex == currentStepIndex &&
          !stepIndicies.includes(currentStepIndex)
        ) {
          stepIndicies.push(currentStepIndex);

          runOnJS(setEndIndex)(endIndex + 1);
          onEndReached && runOnJS(onEndReached)(currentStepIndex);
        }
      },
      [endIndex]
    );

    return <AnimatedFlatList ref={ref} {...props} onScroll={_onScroll} />;
  }
);
export default memo(AnimatedHFlatList);
```